# Query collection with conditions Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a complexe query to do who depend on my parameters, i explain you all :

Here my tables structure :

```
licencies : 
-id 
-lb_name
-type_licence_id
-valid_licence_id 



licencies_medias : 
-id
-licencie_id
-file path
```

I actually made a query who return a collection of licencies with have 2 or more files (licencies_medias)

```
 $licencies = $query->whereIn('type_licence_id' , [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5])
        ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
        ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
        ->has('medias', '>=', 2)
        ->orderBy('lb_name' , 'asc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

> My problem is that the number of medias depend on the type_licence_id
>   :

For exemple a licencie who have type_licence_id = 1 need to have 3 licencies_medias (files)

a licencie who have type_licence_id = 2 need to have 4 licencies_medias (files)

> I need to create a query who can check this conditions and display all
>   the licencies who have the right number of files for the right
>   type_licence_id and display them together

Actually in my model i have :

```
// on licencies model
public function medias()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LicenciesMedias::class , 'licencie_id');
}

// on licenciesMedia model
public function licencie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Licencies::class , 'licencie_id);
}
```

EDIT it's seems to work with merge collection method, only one more problem is when i try to filter the query i get no result: here the full controller :

```
    public function licenceToValidFromFede(Request $request)
    {


//        $licencies_to_search = Licencies::select('structure_id', 'num_licence', 'lb_nom' , 'lb_prenom' , 'id')
//            ->whereIn('type_licence_id' , [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5])
//            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
//            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
//            ->get()
//            ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
//                return [$i->id => $i->num_licence.' - '.$i->lb_nom. ' ' .$i->lb_prenom. ' - ' .$i->structure->num_structure. ' ' .$i->structure->nom_structure];
//            });

        $type_licence = Type_licence::pluck('lb_type' , 'id');

        $activite = ActiviteLicencie::pluck('lb_activite' , 'id');

        $structure = Structure::select('num_structure', 'nom_structure' , 'id')
            ->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
                return [$i->id => $i->num_structure.' - '.$i->nom_structure];
            });

        $catg_licence = CatgLicence::pluck('lb_catg_lic' , 'id');


        $query = Licencies::query();

        $filters = [
            'structure' => 'structure_id',
            'type_licence' => 'type_licence_id',
            'activite_licencie' => 'activite_licencie_id',
            'assurance' => 'lb_assurance_etat',
            'catg_licence' => 'catg_licence_id',

        ];


        foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
            if ($request->has($key)) {
                $query->where($column, $request->{$key});

            }
        }

//        $licencies = $query->whereIn('type_licence_id' , [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5])
//            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
//            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
//            ->has('medias', '=', 2)
//            ->orderBy('lb_nom' , 'asc')
//            ->paginate(10);


        $licencies_id_1 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 1)
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
            ->has('medias', '>=',  2)
            ->get();

        $licencies_id_2 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 2)
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
            ->has('medias', '>=', 3)
            ->get();


        $licencies_id_3 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 3)
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
            ->has('medias', '>=', 3)
            ->get();

        $licencies_id_4 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 4)
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
            ->has('medias', '>=', 3)
            ->get();

        $licencies_id_5 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 5)
            ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
            ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
            ->has('medias', '>=', 3)
            ->get();

        $all_licencies = $licencies_id_1->merge($licencies_id_2);
        $all_licencies = $all_licencies->merge($licencies_id_3);
        $all_licencies = $all_licencies->merge($licencies_id_4);
        $all_licencies = $all_licencies->merge($licencies_id_5);

        $licencies = $all_licencies;

        $perPage = 15;
        $paginator = new Paginator($licencies, $perPage);

        return view('licencie/validerFromFede' , compact('licencies' ,'licencies_to_search' , 'type_licence' , 'activite' , 'structure' , 'catg_licence' ,'paginator'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with more queries.

Foreach version

```
        $filters = [
            'structure' => ['structure_id', 1, 3]
            'type_licence' => ['type_licence_id',2 ,4]

        ];


        $all_licencies = collect();          

        foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
            if ($request->has($key)) {
                $licencies = $query->where($column[0], $request->{$key});
                    ->where('statut_licence_id', $column[1])
                    ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
                    ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
                    ->has('medias', '=', $column[2])
                    ->get();

                $all_licencies = $all_licencies->merge($licencies);

            }

        }
```

---

Hard code version

```
 $licencies_id_1 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 1)
        ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
        ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
        ->has('medias', 3)
        ->get();

 $licencies_id_2 = $query->where('type_licence_id' , 2)
        ->whereIn('statut_licence_id', ['1' , '4'])
        ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
        ->has('medias', 4)
        ->get();
```

Then you can merge them together.

```
$all_licencies = $licencies_id_1->merge($licencies_id_2);
$all_licencies = $all_licencies->merge($licencies_id_3);
```

and so on. And ordered it at the end.

```
$ordered_licencies = $all_licencies->sortBy('lb_name');
```

Comment: Hi james, i didn't know the method merge for collections. this process will save my life. i will try when i'm back at the office and i let you know, many many thanks for your answer

Comment: i get this exception Method appends does not exist.

Comment: i can't pass the method paginate after the merge

Comment: ok i found how to create a paginator manually. just one more problem. i update the post

Comment: i dont understand what you want to do, but you don't your query assign to any variable, and you don't get it right ? like ${var.'_'.$key} = $query->where($column, $request->{$key})->get();

Comment: in my view i have a search form ! yes exactly i don't get it

Comment: further more when i dd the result of the merge i don't get the right amount of licencies. because in each $licencies_id collection i use $query

Comment: and you should use new filtered query instead ? I would prefer add type_licence_id and number of medias to $filters array and do it all with foreach :)

Comment: could you send my the code you have in mind i'm not sure to understand well

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can get all licenses and getting their medias using laravel with relation

$licenses = License::whereIn('type_licence_id' , [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5])
           ->where('valid_licence_id', '1')
           ->with('medias')
           ->get();

// This will get license medias based on the relation defined in the License model. 
// You can get an idea from this, as you should not request individually for each type of 'type_license_id'.
```

Comment: hello i didn't understand very well , with this code i will get all the licences who have medias but not with conditions on the licence table with type_licence_id , could you explain me more but your solution ?